# Fast method for summation over multidimensional arrays with indirect indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What is the optimal (fastest) way to compute the following expression:

\sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i \sum_{j \in J} \beta_j M[:, i, j] for given numpy arrays:

- I, J containing indices;
- alpha and beta of shapes (1, |I|) and (1, |J|) containing coefficients;
- M of ndim=3.

In a more general case, I need to compute it for a lot of alpha, beta, I, J inputs with the same M array. So it may be considered that alphas nad Is have shape (N, 4), betas and Js have shape (N, 3) and I need to compute this expression for each n in range(N).

Thank you in advance.

Based on some comments, to make the question more clear and to add some context, here is a naive approach to the problem with realistic sizes:

`M` has shape `(500, 200000, 20)`

`I` has shape `(10^6, 4)`

`J` has shape `(10^6, 3)`

`alpha` has shape `(10^6, 4)`

`beta` has shape `(10^6, 3)`

```
N = 10**6
M_new = np.zeros(M.shape[0], N)
for n in range(N):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(3):
            M_new[:, n] += alpha[n, i] * beta[n, j] * M[:, I[n, i], J[n, j]]
```

So the question is how to compute M_new as fast as possible.

**Solutions**

So far the fastest solution is the one proposed by @jdehesa using Numba.

@Han-KwangNienhuys presented speed comparison with alternative methods.

Comment: Add your attempts to solve it?

Comment: The optimal solution will depend on whether I and J cover most of the rows/columns of M, or only a small fraction. Also, it depends on whether the elements in I and J are unique. So, you need to make a statement about these assumptions.

Comment: I added more context and naive approach.

Comment: In your code sample: `M[:, I[i], J[j]]`; do you mean `M[:, I[n,i], J[n, j]]`?

Comment: Yes, sure, thx.

Comment: Can you change the title of the question to something that's more likely to be found by people with similar problems in the future? Something like *Fast method for summation over multidimensional arrays with indirect indexing in numpy*.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys Good idea, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
I misunderstood the question in the first place. I left the original answer below but it does not do what the question asks.

At the risk of sounding obvious, you can always resort to Numba:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

# Original loop implementation
def comb_loop(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta):
    n = ii.shape[0]
    m_new = np.zeros((m.shape[0], n))
    for col in range(n):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(3):
                m_new[:, col] += alpha[col, i] * beta[col, j] * m[:, ii[col, i], jj[col, j]]
    return m_new

# Numba implementation
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def comb_nb(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta):
    n = ii.shape[0]
    m_new = np.empty((m.shape[0], n), m.dtype)
    for col in nb.prange(n):
        for row in range(m.shape[0]):
            val = 0
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(3):
                    val += alpha[col, i] * beta[col, j] * m[row, ii[col, i], jj[col, j]]
            m_new[row, col] = val
    return m_new


# Test
np.random.seed(0)
N = 1_000  # Reduced for testing
m = np.random.rand(500, 200_000, 20)
ii = np.random.randint(m.shape[1], size=(N, 4))
jj = np.random.randint(m.shape[2], size=(N, 3))
alpha = np.random.rand(N, 4)
beta = np.random.rand(N, 3)

# Check results match
print(np.allclose(comb_loop(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta), comb_nb(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta)))
# True

# Timings
%timeit comb_loop(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta)
# 181 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit comb_nb(m, ii, jj, alpha, beta)
# 31.1 ms ± 2.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

ORIGINAL WRONG ANSWER

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```py
import numpy as np

def comb(alpha, beta, m):
    return np.einsum('i,j,nij->n', alpha, beta, m)

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
alpha = np.random.rand(10)
beta = np.random.rand(20)
m = np.random.rand(30, 10, 20)
result = comb(alpha, beta, m)
print(result.shape)
# (30,)
```

Comment: i, j are taken from I and J, which don't necessarily have the same length as the last two axes of m. The poster needs to clarify this.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys I added more context

Comment: @makkostya Sorry, I didn't understand your question in the first place. I have added a possible implementation with Numba.

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you for your reply. Using numba didn't sound obvious for me just because I've never used it before. It might indeed be the optimal solution for me, I'll consider it.

Answer (score 2):

With numpy arrays, you can index like this: `a[[1, 7, 5]]`, which is roughly equivalent to `[a[1], a[7], a[5]]`. You can use this to select `M[:, I[n], :]` or `M[:, :, J[n]]`. However, `M[:, I[n], J[n]]` will not work; instead you need to do `M[:, I[n], :][:, :, J[n]]`. Fortunately, the last axis of `M` is small: `M[:, I[n], :]` has shape `(500, 4, 20)`; reducing that to `(500, 4, 3)` is not too much waste of copying. The other way around, `M[:, :, J[n]][:, I[n], :]` would produce the same result, but would have an intermediate result with shape `(500, 200000, 3)`, which would incur vastly more overhead.

Here is how to do it:

```
np.random.seed(1)

# generate test arrays
N, p, q, r = 11, 5, 9, 7    # realistic values 1e6, 500, 2e5, 20
M = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(p, q, r))
mi, mj = 4, 3
I = np.random.randint(0, q-1, size=(N, mi))
J = np.random.randint(0, r-1, size=(N, mj))
alpha = np.random.randint(-99, 99, size=(N, mi))
beta = np.random.randint(-99, 99, size=(N, mj))

# Reference implementation
M_new = np.zeros((M.shape[0], N))
for n in range(N):
    for i in range(mi):
        for j in range(mj):
            M_new[:, n] += alpha[n, i] * beta[n, j] * M[:, I[n, i], J[n, j]]            

# New implementation
M_new2 = np.zeros((p, N))

for n in range(N):
    M_sub = M[:, I[n]][:, :, J[n]] # shape (p, mi, mj)
    M_new2[:, n] = np.einsum('i,j,kij', alpha[n], beta[n], M_sub)


assert np.all(M_new == M_new2)
```

As an alternative to `M[:, I[n], :][:, :, J[n]]`, it's possible to construct two index arrays `ii` and `jj`, both with shape `(4, 3)` so that you can take `M[:, ii, jj]`:

```
M_new3 = np.zeros_like(M_new2)
for n in range(N):
    # ii, jj: shape (mi, mj)
    ii, jj = np.meshgrid(I[n], J[n], indexing='ij')
    M_sub = M[:, ii, jj] # shape (p, mi, mj)
    M_new3[:, n] = np.einsum('i,j,kij', alpha[n], beta[n], M_sub)

assert np.all(M_new == M_new3)
```

However, this is tricky to do right: it's easy to forget the `indexing='ij'` parameter for `np.meshgrid`. For small datasets (`N, p, q, r = 10000, 50, 2000, 20`) it seems to be slower than the first implementation (`M_new2`).

**EDIT**: one more, without any for loops:

```
assert mi*mj*p*N < 1e8 # prevent out-of-memory error

ii = np.empty((N, mi, mj, p), dtype=np.int32)
ii[:] = I.reshape(N, mi, 1, 1)

jj = np.empty((N, mi, mj, p), dtype=np.int32)
jj[:] = J.reshape(N, 1, mj, 1)

kk = np.empty((N, mi, mj, p), dtype=np.int32)
kk[:] = np.arange(p).reshape(1, 1, 1, p)

M_sub = M[kk, ii, jj] # shape (N, mi, mj, p)
M_new4 = np.einsum('ni,nj,nijk->kn', alpha, beta, M_sub)

assert np.all(M_new == M_new4)
```

For the original array sizes, the `ii, jj, kk, M_sub` arrays will each have 6e+9 elements, so you'll need a lot of memory (compared to `M` which has 2e+9 elements). Probably it's useful to split up the job into chunks (along the `N` axis) that each fit in the L3 cache memory of the CPU and also to set up `M_sub` to have shape `(N, p, mi, mj)` in memory (not by reshaping) and `M_new` as `(N, p)`.

### Speed comparison

For `N, p, q, r = 10000, 50, 2000, 20` and integer multiplications:

- Reference: 616 ms
- 2 `M[:, I[n]][:, :, J[n]]`: 171 ms
- 3 `meshgrid(I[n], J[n], indexing='ij')`: 360 ms
- 4 `M[kk, ii, jj]`: 129 ms
- `numba.njit` (from the other answer): 20 ms

Timings include the `assert` statements.

Comment: Thank you, I tested these approaches. It does indeed reduce the computation time, but only by the factor of 2. I think that the bottleneck is the first loop `for n in range(N)`. Can you think a way how to get rid of it?